# NodeJS - Problema ao enviar um POST com array de objeto

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, mongodb, arraylist

Eu estou usando NodeJS + MongoDB, e estou tentando enviar um array de Book, via method POST, mas de alguma forma ele está dando problema, pois ao usar o Postman e clicar em  Send, ele só me retorna:

```
{
    "_id": "5c48cf81a90935079bb12035",
    "createdAt": "2019-01-23T20:33:05.595Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-01-23T20:33:05.595Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

O JSON que eu estou tentando enviar pelo Postman segue este modelo:

```
[
    {
        "title": "A menina que roubava livros",
        "description": "Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro",
        "url": "http://www.amenina.com.br",
        "date": "2018-02-01",
        "owner": "Paulo Coelho"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "A menina que roubava livros 2",
        "description": "Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro",
        "url": "http://www.amenina.com.br",
        "date": "2018-02-01",
        "owner": "Paulo Coelho"
    }
]
```

Em suma: eu preciso enviar um Schema (que estará logo abaixo aqui) via POST usando NodeJS, mas quando tento, ele retorna o JSON acima

Segue os códigos relacionados:

**SCHEMA**

```
[
    {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        url: String,
        data: String,
        owner: [String]
    }   
]
```

> **MODEL**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const BookSchema = mongoose.Schema([
    {
        title: String,
        description: String,
        url: String,
        date: String,
        owner: String
    }], 
{
    timestamps: true
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema)
```

> **ROUTER**

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    const books = require('../controllers/book.controller.js')
    app.post('/books', books.create)
    app.get('/books', books.findAll)
}
```

> **CONTROLLER**

```
const Book = require('../models/book.model.js')
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    const book = new Book(
        {
            title: req.body.title || '',
            description: req.body.description || '',
            url: req.body.url || '',
            date: req.body.date,
            owner: req.body.owner
        }
    ) 

    book.save()
    .then(data => {
        res.send(data)
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Erro em comunicação com o servidor. Tente mais tarde"
        })
    })
}
```

**console.log(req.body)** antes do metodo **book.save()** me retorna os dados preenchidos:

```
[ { title: 'A menina que roubava livros',
    description: 'Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro',
    url: 'http://www.amenina.com.br',
    date: '2018-02-01',
    owner: 'Paulo Coelho' },
  { title: 'A menina que roubava livros 2',
    description: 'Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro',
    url: 'http://www.amenina.com.br',
    date: '2018-02-01',
    owner: 'Paulo Coelho' } ]
```

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Poderia explicar um pouco melhor o problema e o que deseja fazer?

Comment: Qual problema? Está mostrando algum erro no console?

Comment: Arrumei a descrição, me digam se está mais legível, qualquer coisa, tento explicar de outra forma

Comment: Ele não mostra erro no console, mas não envia o array de dados corretamente

Comment: Faça um `console.log(req.body)` antes de salvar o livro e coloque na pergunta

Comment: Ele mostra os dados preenchidos @GuilhermeCostamilam

Comment: Foi o que pensei, recebe um array mas tenta salvar como se fosse um objeto, o que acontece é que o resultado ao criar um Book ele retorna um objeto com os campos `undefined`

Comment: Muito obrigado galera, muito obrigado a todos aqui, consegui com a solução abaixo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você está enviando um array, mas ta salvando como se fosse um unico objeto. 
recomendo que você envie um Array nesse formado

```
{
books:[
    {
        "title": "A menina que roubava livros",
        "description": "Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro",
        "url": "http://www.amenina.com.br",
        "date": "2018-02-01",
        "owner": "Paulo Coelho"
    }, 
    {
        "title": "A menina que roubava livros 2",
        "description": "Uma garota que adorava ir pra biblioteca roubar livro",
        "url": "http://www.amenina.com.br",
        "date": "2018-02-01",
        "owner": "Paulo Coelho"
    }
]
}
```

assim tu poderá acessar o JSON a partir do `req.body.books`; exemplo:

```
    const books = req.body.books;

    for (let i = 0; i < books.books.length; i++) {
        const item = books[i];

        const book = new Book(
        {
            title: item.title || '',
            description: item.description || '',
            url: item.url || '',
            date: item.date,
            owner: item.owner
        }) 

        book.save()

    }
```

Comment: Pode simplificar o loop e usar a sintaxe `for (const item of books) ...`

Comment: Nesse caso também seria interessante usar o `Promise.all` para fazer uma melhor tratativa de erros.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado cara, e obrigado a todos aqui também!